# Newton's Method on C++

Tags: c++

Okay, I'm trying to put my Newton into this C++, and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double x1, x0;
  int n,i;

  cin >> x0, n;

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
      x1 = x0 - ((4.0*pow(x0,3.0)-2.0*pow(x0,2.0)+3.0)/(12.0*pow(x0,2.0)-4.0*x0)); #problem
      x0 = x1;
  }

  cout << x1;
  return 0;
}
```

Okay, maybe my code isn't well described to you, but the question is the #problem part, when I put this on for iteration method, it compiled nicely no errors given, but when I run, it takes long time, and just freeze on the input of x0, n (see the code before iteration), even if I insert the n = 1, but delete the iteration, it runs well, and give the expected answer (in this case I can't make iteration, similar to n = 1). What's the reason of it? Because I want to do the 4 iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cin >> x0, n;
```

That only reads into `x0`, leaving `n` containing a garbage value. To read into both, you want

```
cin >> x0 >> n;
```

Remember to enable compiler warnings: most compilers will detect mistakes like this.